# Kicking off a Performance Monitor Data Collector Set via PowerShell?

Tags: c#, performance, powershell

I have a need to kick off a Data Collector Set that I've predefined. I'm going to be writing a PowerShell script that monitors a condition on the system and when it detects that condition, it begins the Data Collector Set. How can I start this Data Collector Set?

Comment: what's a "data collector set?" (i'm a powershell mvp, but I don't know a ton about admin stuff)

Comment: It's part of Performance Logs and Alerts. If you open up Computer Management and then expand Performance and Data Collector Sets. Right click on User Defined and create a new Data Collector Set. When the wizard comes up, create it from the System Performance template. Then start the Data Collector Set, let it run for a minute or two and then go to the reports section of Performance. It will have generated a report based on watching one minute of system performance data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a .NET way to do this but I do know you can use logman.exe to start/stop these e.g.:

```
logman start "My DataCollectorSet"
logman stop "My DataCollectorSet"
```

Comment: This is sufficient for me. Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell can easily stop/start (and query the current-state) of Data Collector Sets using members of the ServerManagerTasks module. For example, [Get-SMPerformanceCollector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanagertasks/start-smperformancecollector?view=win10-ps) can be used to query the state of a collector, and then you can use Start-GetSMPerformanceCollector or Stop accordingly... 
-

Answer (score 4):

You can also access the collector sets programmatically by referencing the PLA.dll assembly in  %windir%\System32\PLA.dll (Vista or later).  You can then start a collection with code similar to:

```
IDataCollectorSet cs = new DataCollectorSet();
cs.Query("Collector set name", null);
cs.start(false);
```

Feel free to translate that to powershell :)